# Using GPU significantly slows down the CPU

Tags: windows, graphics-card, cpu, performance, gpu

My Dell XPS 15 9560 laptop has 2 GPUs:

- Intel HD Graphics 630
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050

It has an Intel i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.8 GHz.

After I play a video game for about 5-10 minutes, the CPU clock speed drops to 0.78 Ghz.  The game uses the NVIDIA GPU. This happens consistently. And obviously, the game is unplayable.

I thought it might the CPU temperatures, so I checked them using CoreTemp app, and they are not bad.  Roughly around 70 C.

To further rule out the CPUs, I ran Prime95 torture test and the clock speed never dropped.
Then I ran the MSI Kombustor GPU stress test, and predictably after about 4-5 minutes, the CPU dropped to 0.78 GHz.

So clearly running the GPU for an extended time period slows down the CPU quite significantly.

What can I do to fix this?

P.S. If I force the game to use the slower Intel GPU, the game just lags and is pretty much unusable - so that's not an option.

More info.
I am on Windows 10 version 2004.
16 GB of RAM
The CPU is quad-core.
The game I play is Age of Empires 2 Definitive Edition.

Comment: What temperature does the GPU get up to? You can use [GPU-z](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) to find out but it does sound like thermal throttling. You can also check other temperatures with programs like hwinfo. It could be that your GPU or another temperature gets high and your firmware starts limiting CPU to control it, 70C with rock bottom clocks suggests *something* is getting hot.

Comment: @Mokubai The GPU temp is now shown in the Task Manager under the Performance tab.  At Idle, the GPU is about 55 degrees.  Once I start the Kombustor GPU stress test, it goes up to around 77 and stays there.  I understand the part about throttling, but why throttle the CPU, the it's the GPU that's the problem.

Comment: The problem is that many laptops share a heatpipe cooling system between the CPU and GPU, so what affects one side will bleed into the other. You hope it's not the case for yours but independent or higher power cooling  tends to be found in the higher end gaming laptops.

Comment: @Mokubai So is there a fix to this issue?  Or is the video card busted?

Comment: Usually open it up and make sure that thermal paste is good (i.e. replace it) and that the fans spin properly and to clean out any dust bunnies that may have accumulated. If that doesn't improve things then play less demanding games or turn down the framerate.